# Did Han Solo know that Anakin Skywalker was Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, return-of-the-jedi, anakin-skywalker, han-solo

Did Han know in the timeline of the Original Trilogy that Darth Vader was Anakin Skywalker and subsequently Leia's father? It would be better if Han Solo knows his Father-in-law.

Comment: Although, he wouldn't have been his Father-in-law until after ROTJ, when Han and Leia actually got married.....

Comment: I never heard of Anakin's name in the original trilogy. And I don't think I even heard his name mentioned in The Force Awakens.

Comment: It does seem kind of strange that a force-wielding evil badass who was known throughout the galaxy for exterminating the Jedi and being the Emperor's lap dog was not more well-known to people like Luke (not to mention Han). Even if Luke's aunt and uncle were aware of this and were trying to protect him by not revealing his father's true identity it seems about as silly as somebody not knowing who Adolf Hitler was while he was actively rounding people up and waging war in Europe. Did they not have Fox News on Tatooine and Corellia?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary - Vader tends to operate behind the scenes.

Comment: @Andrew, Anakin's name is mentioned by Obi Wan in the original trilogy.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary: Did you see any television sets, or even radio, in Owen's dwelling? I didn't.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary - most interactions with Vader are by officials or troops of the Empire, or, to any memorable degree, by people who meet their demise at his hands, so it's understandable that there isn't a lot of direct knowledge about him floating around.

Comment: The entirely non cannon "Lego: Star Wars Chronicles" supports the idea he didn't know. As he finds out the day after the battle of Endor.

Comment: What?? Anakin Skywalker is Darth Vader?!?! Damn spoiler!

Comment: @Andrew Luke also tells his father in ROTJ that "I know you were once Anakin Skywalker, my father", so clearly he too knows his father's original name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### No.

There's absolutely nothing in the Original Trilogy films (nor their novelisations) to indicate that Han learned of Vader's identity.

Luke refers to Vader as his father in his coversation *with Leia*, but there's nothing to show that Han was subsequently told this secret, at least prior to the end of the film.

> “Oh, no. No.” She laughed, “it’s not like that at all—Luke is my
> brother.”  **Han was successively stunned, embarrassed, and elated. This
> made everything fine, just fine.**
>
> He took her in his arms, embraced her, lowered her back down into the
> ferns … and being extra careful of her wounded arm, lay down there
> beside her, under the waning glow of the burning Star.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Return of the Jedi - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

I'd imagine *if she'd already told him that Vader was Luke's father*, his thought process would have been more like...

> “Oh, no. No.” She laughed, “it’s not like that at all—Luke is my
> brother.”  **"Bloody hell," thought Han. "But surely that means that Darth Vader was her father too!"**

---

That all being said, Han evidently did find out some time in the intervening 20 years between Return of the Jedi and The Force Awakens;

> *What could he say to that? What possible response could he give to a
> willful denial of reason? “He’s gone, Leia. He was always drawn to the
> dark side. There was nothing we could’ve done to stop it, no matter
> how hard we tried.” His final words were the hardest to get out.
> **“There was too much Vader in him.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: But the question is,"does han solo knows anakin skywalker"?

Comment: @augustine08282011 Do you mean if he ever met him? This doesn't seem to be your original question, though.

Comment: @augustine08282011 - Good question. I'm at a loss how Han could know that Leia and Luke are bro/sis and that Vader is their father without joining the dots and working out that her father was noted (and famous) Jedi warrior Anakin Skywalker.

Comment: Cahir Mawr Dyffryn æp Ceallach, I'm not  asking if Han solo and Anakin ever met.

Comment: Novelization Quotes vs. Youtube Clips.... :-D

Comment: @Skooba Next time just answer a *Harry Potter* question with a movie scene. People will love *that*. ;-)

Comment: @Skooba - Both valid sources, but I'd assume that the OP has already seen the film and is looking for *additional* sources of info.

Comment: @Valorum Do we have any reason to believe that Anakin Skywalker was famous in-universe? Individual Jedi don't seem to be particularly well-known figures.

Comment: @JustinLardinois - Apparently Anakin and Obi-Wan were pretty well-known; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111698/20774

Comment: @Valorum You know I love you and your novelizations!

Comment: @Valorum Right at the start of the OT it's established that at least the military thinks the Force is simply a religion and the Jedi are just a legend. There's no reason to assume the general populace is aware of the fact that it was all real during the OT.

Comment: @Kevin - given that there were approx 1 jedi for every fifty billion sentients, it's not especially surprising that many people assume they were a myth, especially given Imperial repression of their archives, news footage, holonet records after the war, etc.

Comment: @Valorum I don't think it's surprising at all, but you seem to assume that because by the time of Revenge of the Sith Anakin and Obi-Wan are famous they are still so by the time of a New Hope. I don't think this is true as it's clearly established right from the start that the Jedi have become an unverifiable myth. Not a single Jedi is famous by that time, as everybody thinks they never existed in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin: In “A New Hope”, the military doesn’t seem to value the Force, but they aren’t really surprised when Vader uses the Force to choke one guy. So it rather seems that they don’t see the strategic significance (in a galactic war) of being able to strangulate a single guy remotely, compared with the new ability to destroy an entire planet. They know that the Force is a thing, but they might not have an idea of what you can do with it (besides occasionally choking someone). On the other hand, Luke has never heard of Yoda, that does tell us something about the popularity of “famous Jedi”…

Comment: Good answer Valorum and Skooba

Answer (score 45):

It depends on how you define "timeline of the Original Trilogy" - if you mean only what is shown on the screen, then Skooba and Valorum's answers are correct.

If you take timeline a bit more broadly, and from an in-universe perspective, just a *single day* after the end of *Return of the Jedi*, then the answer is:

**Yes - Han knew.**

From the new canon novel **Bloodline**:

> Their romance had been so new then. Only the day before, he had offered to step aside if she wanted Luke instead. Would he be even quicker to leave once he knew she was a part of Darth Vader himself? But Han hadn't even flinched once. He had simply rocked her in his arms, giving her what comfort he could.
> <sub>Bloodline - Kindle version (Chapter 23)</sub>

Comment: Good find. You have my +1

Comment: In the quote from Bloodline, you wrote 'But Had', instead of 'But Han'. Nice find indeed :-)

Comment: But he don't know he's the father of Leila

Comment: Disney did declare the extended universe null and void when they acquired the franchise, tho. Mostly so nobody could tell them the films contradict the various sequel novels.

Comment: @AJFaraday - Bloodline is a new canon novel overseen by the Lucasfilm Story Group. All novels released (and comics), starting with "A New Dawn" are considered canon.

Comment: @NKCampbell Well, that's put me in my place :p

Comment: @AJFaraday - no worries :)

Comment: I am impressed this answer has taken then #1 spot even though it was the last answer posted! Kudos, it deserves it!

Answer (score 33):

Han **did not** find out about the Vader/Anakin connection before the end of *Return of the Jedi*.

Luke had previously told Leia that Vader was his father, and then that she was his sister.

But when Leia tells Han she and Luke are siblings, she does not go further and reveal who their father is.

Han was either told later or was able to connect the dots prior to the events in *The Force Awakens*. Han says this while discussing his and Leia's son:

> *"He has too much Vader in him."*

Comment: does he really know it? He just only know luke not anakin.

Comment: @augustine08282011 Maybe not at that split second, but all the evidence is there.

Comment: But after this dialogue he only seems to know about the Luke-Leia relation. I'm not sure he really knows about their connection to Vader *during* the film (he definitely knows in *The Force Awakens*, though, which also makes sense, it's nothing you keep to yourself).

Comment: @Skooba What evidence? How would anyone assume that evil masked guy is coincidentally also Luke's long-lost father?

Comment: @Skooba - I've gotta agree with Augustine08282011. He finds out that Luke and Leia are bro/sis, but there's no indication that she told Han that Vader was Luke's father.

Comment: Leia didn't mentioned that Darth vader is my father to han solo.She only says that Luke is her brother.

Comment: @Valorum alright then, I see your point. Hopefully the edit can remove some downvotes.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. +2

Comment: He wasn't told on-screen, but he probably found out soon enough, though. After all, he must have had a few questions about why Luke hauled Vader's body back, and made a pyre for him.

Answer (score 1):

The (Non Cannon) Lego "Star Wars Droid Tales" shows Han Finding out. After the battle of Endor. When R2D2 gives C3PO his memory back.

> Luke -Then you two fought in the Clone Wars with Obi-Wan?
>
> C3PO - Indeed. And with Master Yoda and your father, before he became Darth Vader, of course.
>
> Han - Wait, what? Luke's father is Darth Vader?
>
> Luke - Everybody knows that. We learned of it months ago.
>
> Han - I was frozen in carbonite. Sue me!

Comment: Someone must really hate the lego star wars things